# How to get the userId field in Azure Devops API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have to use this API : PATCH [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/_apis/userentitlements/%7BuserId%7D) to give read access to some projects to all users in my organisation. I am able to call this API, with success, but I don't know how to get the right GUID for the users. (To get the right Guid for the user I used Fiddler to spy the request).

When I use this API, (GET [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganisation%7D/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1)) I get all users of my organisation, but in the list, there no the userId, I have only the originId, and it is the guid from the AAD, and I cannot update the user with that information.

I tried too to use the descriptor field, without any success. Does somebody have an idea to get this specific userId?

Example of User list I get with this API :

```
{
    "count": 133,
    "value": [{
        "subjectKind": "user",
        "metaType": "member",
        "directoryAlias": "COD0001",
        "domain": "10a83eaa-05c5-4b22-a201-63cddba4fe8c",
        "principalName": "bidon.person@example.com",
        "mailAddress": "bidon.person@example.com",
        "origin": "aad",
        "originId": "7c3408d6-62f4-43ff-bdbe-5be97000ba30",
        "displayName": "Personne bidon",
        "_links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/Graph/Users/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
            },
            "memberships": {
                "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/Graph/Memberships/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
            },
            "membershipState": {
                "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/Graph/MembershipStates/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
            },
            "storageKey": {
                "href": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/Graph/StorageKeys/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
            },
            "avatar": {
                "href": "https://dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
            }
        },
        "url": "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/BIDON/_apis/Graph/Users/aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx",
        "descriptor": "aad.ZDYzNzUwNzctNWJjYy03ZTkzLWIzZGUtMDEzNTdhM2JiMDIx"
    },
    ...
    ]
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get id you should use [User Entitlements - Search User Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/search%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) which is

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3
```

then you will get response like

```json
"members": [
        {
            "id": "<YOUR ID HERE>",
            "user": {
                "subjectKind": "user",
                "metaType": "member",
                "domain": "Windows Live ID",
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use az cli.

1 - First you need to install the az cli extension if it is not installed.

```
az extension list-available --output table | grep devops
az extension add --name azure-devops
```

2 - Configure organization if is needed

```
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/myorganization
```

3 - maybe you need to do a login and insert de devops PAT token (paste it)

```
az devops login
token:
```

4 - Use de command user list with the option --top if you need to show more than 200 users

```
az devops user list --top 15000
```

5 - Use pipe with grep command to filter or send it to a file to find the user that you want to find.

```
az devops user list --top 15000 > devops-users.txt
az devops user list --top 5000 | grep myemail@mycompany.com
```

6 - the field that you want is the id:

```
  "id": "a69fdd3c-yyyyy-6fa6-90ba-xxxxxx",
```

If you has permissions you can use also de command az devops user show

```
az devops user show --user myemail@mycompany.com
```

Docs:

[install az cli extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-overview)

[az devops user](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cli/azure/devops/user?view=azure-cli-latest)

Answer (score 0):

Use this API to get all of the user's information in the organization.

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

If you want to get a particular user by the Id, use this API:

```
GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=5.1-preview.2
```

By using these APIs, you will able to fetch the user details from the object id.